# ExtJSv7: Error while implementing Ext.mixin.Observable

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs7

We are trying to implement `Ext.mixin.Observable` in our ViewController, snippet below

```
mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Observable'],
constructor: function(config){
  this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this, config);
},
```

but this raises an error for `this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this, config);` in Viewcontroller

```
BaseController.js?_dc=1587282588103:440 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined
    at constructor.listen (BaseController.js?_dc=1587282588103:440)
    at constructor.callParent (Base.js?_dc=1587282588090:1479)
    at constructor.listen (ViewController.js?_dc=1587282588091:206)
    at constructor.updateListen (BaseController.js?_dc=1587282588103:257)
    at constructor.setter [as setListen] (Config.js?_dc=1587282588102:329)
    at Ext.Configurator.configure (Configurator.js?_dc=1587282588102:674)
    at constructor.initConfig (Base.js?_dc=1587282588090:1650)
    at constructor (Observable.js?_dc=1587282588091:437)
    at constructor (MainController.js?_dc=1587282588090:6)
```

what could be wrong here, I followed the documentation given on sencha docs for `Ext.mixin.Observable`

Answer (score 0):

Look like you miss `this.callParent(arguments)` in constructor after call observable constructor

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'someevent' of undefined`

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/35ba
all work fine in my example. Please, try create fiddle with your issue. And why you can try use Observable on ViewController? It's not a component. what is your idea?